# How can we compare the decision trees algorithm performance in terms of accuracy from scikit-learn and from Spark ML?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml

I am comparing the accuracy for text classification obtained using sklearn DT and Spark ML DT with same features and dataset. Is it appropriate to even compare them? The reason being, the parameters list is different for both of them so I think results will differ and I am not sure on what basis we can compare them? Which one should result in better accuracy and performance in the default settings? I know it depends upon from use case to use case, but can we generalize it at least for the same use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two algorithm, with different hyperparameters. but the accuracy measure(the metric for comparision) must be exactly the same. For example you can use AUC(area under the curve) metric, both for Sickit and Mlib. Notice that, the datasets and features must also be the same.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html

Comment: My concern is, the default parameters for Spark ML and sklearn are different. For eg, max depth is None for sklearn and 5 for Spark ML. This will change the accuracy score even if the dataset and features are same. So how do can you compare the final accuracy achieved if the default values for the parameters and the parameters itself are different? Or is it like we can't compare it?

Comment: @Alvin, It is comparable, Do you familiar with Grid Search? It exists in Spark, also Sickit, Try to optimize the parameters with Grid Search and then compare together.